# Displaying *s on console when reading password

Tags: c++, console-application, brute-force

I have been trying to make a brute-force program in C++, for a school project, but I want to make the password you enter censored, so instead of like password it would be ********
PS it's an console application

This is my C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char chars[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','W','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
string t;

void checkPassword(string password);
void recurse(int width, int position, string baseString);
int  main() {
  cout << "Enter a Password: " << endl;

  cin >> t;
  int maxChars = 13;
  for(int i=0;i<maxChars+1;i++) {
    cout << "checking passwords width [" << i << "]..." << endl;
    recurse(i,0,"");

  }
  return 0;
}
void recurse(int width, int position, string baseString) {
  for(int i=0;i<70;i++) {
    if (position < width-1) {
      recurse(width, position + 1, baseString+chars[i]);
    }
    checkPassword(baseString+chars[i]);
  }
}
void checkPassword(string password) {
  if (password==t) {
    cout << "Match Found: " << password << "" << endl;
    return;
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot but I can't seem to get it working, thanks in advance.

Comment: please improve  your question showing where you doscovered "not works". It's a good idea to first limit yourself to max 2-letter passwords, that you can just follow; Make a test suite that searches for pre-set passwords like "4", "a2"... and you can write out trace of what gets tried

Comment: Console manipulation is not part of the C++ standard so you will have to rely on things specific to your environment (Windows, Linux, Mac etc) or potentially even to the console you are using.

Comment: Ncurses on Linux will do it.
http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses

Answer (score 0):

A console program doesn't have the capabilities to do this. If you're working on a Windows machine and don't need any cross-platform portability, you may be able to get away with using the non-standard [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) library's `getch()` function to simulate `cin` while replacing the characters. But I honestly recommend against a roundabout approach like that. If you really need the censorship of the password, I suggest that you either turn the program into a GUI application or ask the user to type their password into a file and then give the filename (so that it doesn't appear onscreen as directly).

Comment: So how do I make this in to a GUI application, like how would it look and work? (I am quite new with C++)

Comment: "A console program doesn't have the capabilities to do this" - Huh? Are you trying to suggest that a Turing machine only works with a VGA color display? Or what?

Comment: As I understood it the main problem in this question was the conversion of input characters to * onscreen. I was simply stating that a console program cannot manipulate what the user types on-screen if you're using `cin`, which as far as I know is true. I wasn't questioning C++'s ability to brute force a password by any means.

Comment: Now I am pretty darn confused

Comment: I think some of us are confused about your question. The way I read it was that you wanted advice on how to turn the input into * characters onscreen, but it seems that most other people read it as you asking for help with the actual logic of the program. Which is it you need help with exactly?

Comment: I want the input into * onscreen, so while I am typing my password it changes to *, like on a HTML form when you set type="password"

Comment: @MauritzN I have edited the post title to (hopefully) clarify your intent.

Comment: Then what I said originally is what you want. There are several OS-specific workarounds that may allow you to do this (just search Google with your particular OS if you want to try and find one), but there's no cross-platform or standardized means of manipulating the console.

Comment: Okay, well I am on windows, but I still don't get exactly where to put the code